# Reading a file that contains an array with Java

Tags: java, arrays, file

I am working on a machin learning algorithm that consist on two parts training and predicting for this I have to save the training results inside a file in order to use them later.
The array is declared this way:

```
List<int[][]> samples = new ArrayList<>();
```

and for the file I used :

```
BufferedWriter writer1 = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("results/samples.data"));
writer1.write(Arrays.deepToString(samples.toArray()));
writer1.close();
```

So the file contains a multidimensional array as in this picture

[image: File Array]

I am already stuck on how to read it and store in inside a variable in the correct form and the searches in most cases the solution was to read the file line by line which is not my case since there's no line breaks

I am asking if there's any way to read the file or if there's is a better solution than the one I am using .

Comment: It looks like JSON. Use a JSON parser.

Comment: If you don't need to store the array in the file in a human-readable format (so that you can see it in a text editor) but are happy to have it stored in a binary format, consider using ObjectOutputStream and ObjectInputStream instead. Then your I/O code will be very simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given

```
[[[1,3][2,5]]
 [[4,8][3,1]]
 [[5,9][6,5]]]
```

I would store the ints only with delimiters

```
1 3 ~ 2 5 | 4 8 ~ 3 1 | 5 9 ~ 6 5
```

It is easy to write and read/parse back with simple for loops or lambdas

**EDIT**
Seems to work this way:

```
public static void main(String[] arg) throws Exception {

    // NESTED ARRAYS EXAMPLE
    List<int[][]> nestedlist = Arrays.asList(
        new int[][] { new int[] {1, 3}, new int[] {2, 5} },
        new int[][] { new int[] {4, 8}, new int[] {3, 1} },
        new int[][] { new int[] {5, 9}, new int[] {6, 5} }
    );

    String s = makeStringForNestedArrays(nestedlist);
    System.out.println(s);

    List<Integer[][]> readNestedList = parseStringToNestedArrays(s);
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(readNestedList.toArray()));


    // SIMPLE ARRAYS EXAMPLE
    List<Integer> simpleList = Arrays.asList(1, 3, 5, 6);

    s = makeStringForSimpleList(simpleList);
    System.out.println(s);

    List<Integer> readSimpleList = parseStringToSingleList(s);
    System.out.println(readSimpleList);

  }

  private static String makeStringForSimpleList(List<Integer> list) {
    return list.stream().map(String::valueOf).collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
  }

  private static List<Integer> parseStringToSingleList(String s) {
    return Arrays.stream(s.split(" ")).map(Integer::valueOf).collect(Collectors.toList());
  }

  private static String makeStringForNestedArrays(List<int[][]> list) {
    return list.stream().
        map(arrayOfArrays -> arrayOfArraysToString(arrayOfArrays))
        .collect(Collectors.joining(" | "));
  }

  private static List<Integer[][]> parseStringToNestedArrays(String s) {
    return Arrays.stream(s.split(" \\| "))
        .map(str -> stringToArrayOfArrays(str, " ~ ", " "))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
  }

  private static String arrayToString(int[] array) {
    return Arrays.stream(array).mapToObj(String::valueOf).collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
  }
  private static String arrayOfArraysToString(int[][] arrayOfArrays) {
    return Arrays.stream(arrayOfArrays).map(array -> arrayToString(array)).collect(Collectors.joining(" ~ "));
  }


  private static Integer[] stringToArray(String s, String delimiter) {
    String[] a = s.split(delimiter);
    return Arrays.stream(a).map(Integer::valueOf).toArray(Integer[]::new);
  }
  private static Integer[][] stringToArrayOfArrays(String s, String delimiterLevel1, String delimiterLevel2) {
    String[] a = s.split(delimiterLevel1);
    return Arrays.stream(a).map(s1 -> stringToArray(s1, delimiterLevel2)).toArray(Integer[][]::new);
  }
```

Comment: could you please make an edit you make that code support also a file with simple array like `[23,15,26,58]`

Comment: do you mean having `List<int[]>` instead of `List<int[][]>` ?

Comment: no i just want it to support both `List<int[][]>` and `List<integer>`

Comment: Here you go. Examples with single lists too.

Answer (score 1):

The usual approach to read arrays from a file is to specify the length of the array in the first line, followed by n lines, where n is the length. This way, you know how big the allocated array should be, and then you read n next lines in a for loop. For 2D arrays, just nest this approach, so that the file could look like something like this:

for array:

```
[[1, 2][3]]
```

create a file like this:

```
2    // length of the outer array
2    // length of the first inner array
1    // first element of the first array
2    // second element of the second array
1    // size of the second array
3    // first element of the second array
```

If you'd like to generalize the approach for N-dimensional arrays, simply just add one line to the beginning, specifying the dimension.